# Javascript съедает всю оперативку

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется js код, рисующий часы и дату в html файл. Проблема в том, что при просмотре файла в браузере, постепенно съедается вся доступная оперативная память.

```
function clock(){
  window.onload = setInterval(clock,1000);

  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getDate();

  var month = d.getMonth();
  var montharr =["January",
               "February",
               "March",
               "April",
               "May",
               "June",
               "July",
               "August",
               "September",
               "October",
               "November",
               "Dececmber"];
  month=montharr[month];

  var year = d.getFullYear();

  var day = d.getDay();
  var dayarr =["Sunday",
             "Monday",
             "Tuesday",
             "Wednesday",
             "Thursday",
             "Friday",
             "Saturday"];
  day=dayarr[day];

  var hour =d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  var sec = d.getSeconds();

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=hour+":"+min+":"+sec;
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=month+" "+date+" "+year+", "+day+" ";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем у вас setInterval внутри clock? Вы каждую секунду запускаете новый таймер. Конечно память будет утекать.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я хочу, чтобы таймер считал секунды. Есть способ без setInterval?

Comment: Ну прочитайте что setInterval делает. И прочитайте внимательно мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval должен быть вне функции.